# Cannot find symbol variable main

Tags: java, android

I am trying to follow this tutorial

http://instinctcoder.com/android-studio-sqlite-database-example/

But I am getting an issue with MainActivity.java:

```
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

For some reason it can't find the symbol "main". I don't know what this means or how to properly resolve it.

I also get the same issue here:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.student_detail, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Here it can't find the symbol "student_detail"

Comment: If you have the main.xml and student_detail.xml files under your res/menu folder, then what you need to do is clean your project and rebuild it.

Comment: I tried that already by doing alt+enter on the symbols and doing "create menu resource file" but all it did is make a near-empty xml file or two under res/menu. The tutorial doesn't seem to mention any such thing. When I ran the app on the phone, it crashed instantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means you are missing the xml files
`main.xml`
and
`student_detail.xml`
in your  resources/menu folder.

Click on your menu folder and right click and press new.. create new menu resource file.

[image: Add menu xml]

Make sure that the names match and you will be responsible for filling the contents of this file.

`<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>`

I am not sure why this isn't being auto-generated when you create each new activity.

It is also good to clean your project and sync project with gradle files, as shown in image below.

[image: Sync project with gradle files]

Comment: Same problem, the app runs and then I click the "Add" button, and it crashes: "Unfortunately, SQLiteDB has stopped."

Comment: No, in the program (this tutorial is for SQLite integration with Android). When you run the program there are two buttons: Add and List All. When you click List All, it gives a message: "No student!" which is fine, but click Add and it crashes.

Comment: Oh, interesting: 01-29 23:55:51.017  23858-23858/com.instinctcoder.sqlitedb E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.instinctcoder.sqlitedb, PID: 23858
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.instinctcoder.sqlitedb/com.instinctcoder.sqlitedb.StudentDetail}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Looks like I needed to add "<activity android:name=".StudentDetail" android:label="@string/title_activity_student_detail"></activity>" to the Manifest. I have no idea why, though.

Comment: Android Studio. Would there be any particular reason why this stuff isn't auto-generating?

Comment: No, haven't renamed. Just created the class files, pasted in the contents.